Distributing datasets partly built with GPLv3 library
We are planning to distribute some domain specific datasets which is the output of a complex ETL process. One of the steps of the process uses a GPLv3 library. Does this mean we have to open source the entire pipeline source code? We are not distributing the pipeline code, only the results.

Are you actually distributing your pipeline to anyone? If not, the GPL obligations kick in only on distribution so are irrelevant. If you are distributing it, please edit your question (don't comment) to give a lot more detail as to exactly how the steps of your pipeline interact.

Unless something really weird is going on, the output of your ETL pipeline is not a derivative work of the pipeline code itself and the copyright license of the one does not affect the copyright license of the other.
This means that using a GPLv3 licensed library in your pipeline only affects the license choices you have for your pipeline code and not in any way the choices you have for the datasets.
If you ever decide to distribute your ETP pipeline code (to other legal entities), then the GPLv3 library mandates that you do that distribution effectively under the GPLv3 license. But that only gives you obligations towards the people that have received a copy of the pipeline code, not to the rest of the world.
